# Access FTP via Proxy using command line

Tags: proxy, ftp

I need to be able to upload/download files to FTP via a proxy server as FTP access is blocked. All this being an automated script, I did find net2ftp.com but they don't have command line feature yet.

I have been using NCFTPGET and NCFTPPUT all this while, but on networks which have FTP blocked, I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an alternate method `wget` which can use proxies for downloading from FTP and HTTP as well.

Read the manual here -> http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

**Update**

I have moved over to cURL , its a much better refined command line tool. More details -> http://curl.haxx.se/